# Why is discrimination based on citizenship allowed in PhD funding in the UK?

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom, international-students

This question is specifically aiming at the UK PhD admission system.

Having spent roughly 6 years in the UK - 2 years A-Level and 4 years undergraduate, I am now moving forward into applying for PhD programs. To my surprise, I discovered that I would have to face a lot of difficulties regarding my eligibility for funding.

Most of the funding I applied for were strictly 'UK/EU citizens only', and it is rare to have full funding for international students. I have applied to a lot of places, and received a lot of responses in the form of "... you are a good match, but I don't have funding for overseas students...".

Having chosen the UK to study with the belief that 'as long as I am competent I should be qualified for the job', the reality has really slapped back at me.

Why such discriminations are allowed in a developed country like the UK? I made this claim knowing little to nothing about the US or other countries' systems, but lots of my friends having applied to EU PhDs received their offers without being asked whether they are 'caucasians' or not.

Comment: Related: [What are interests of a country to fund international PhD students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65187/what-are-interests-of-a-country-to-fund-international-phd-students)

Comment: Were the funding declined because you said you were not "caucasian"? If the reason was citizenship and not race, that last comment is superfluous.

Comment: I got declined because I was not qualified for 'UK/EU citizenship'... the caucasian there was just a childish use of words, I admit.

Comment: This question is pretty much a rant, but as you have received a useful answer (and I think there is indeed an important question for international students in the UK here), I decided against voting to close.

Comment: A very simplified explanation: because the money for that funding is provided by the taxpayers of that country. The citizens of that country have to pay taxes, part of which goes to education. Some percentage of the taxes are used to fund international students, but not all. Calling that discrimination looks like someone who was barred from entering a movie theater without buying a ticket, and called discrimination when other people, who have bought tickers, are let in.

Comment: This is not 'discrimination' in the eyes of UK law, because citizenship is not a protected characteristic. Also, being in the UK purely for education is explicitly excluded from measures of time spent living in the UK, so how long you have been here is irrelevant. Also, the US is no different - there were jobs I couldn't get because I'm not a US citizen, and some where I suspect it had an indirect effect even if it wasn't an explicit requirement.

Comment: A precise statement @vsz. I suggest you rather post it as an answer than a comment.

Comment: @vsz: but international students have to pay *twice* as much compared to UK students already. Adding the extra restriction onto limited funding creates an extra disadvantage...

Comment: -1. For the accusation of "discrimination". If there was no distinction between "citizen" and "non-citizen", then citizenship would not exist. That's not, for better or worse, how human society works.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why -1? It is a discrimination. It's a fact. You even contradict yourself in the next sentence, clearly calling it a "distinction", and explaining one of the reasons. I don't think discrimination is necessarily unjust. Reference [discriminate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discriminate).

Comment: @Quang Thinh Ha: If a Briton were to go to your native country for education, what chance would that person have to get PhD funding?

Comment: @luk32: the OP is using "discrimination" in the sentence "Why such discriminations are allowed in a developed country like the UK?". He is using it as something negative, that according to him shouldn't happen in an advanced society.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Personally I don't see any bias or negativity. Even if there was. So what? Does that makes question invalid, or the word? I don't see how this would justify a downvote. This isn't a loaded question, or a lot less than "Why beating a wife is bad?" - This one assumes the point, that it's not proper. OP doesn't even suggest the policy is wrong... There is an obvious discrimination, how would you rephrase "*Why such discriminations are allowed in a developed country like the UK?*" with out losing the point?

Comment: @luk32: from my point of view, I feel the question as a rant. Because on its bare bones, the question is "why do citizens have benefits that non-citizens don't have?". Note also that my downvote is not the only one.

Comment: 1. It is a discrimination, based on citizenship. That's clear. 2. It is justified to a certain extent, as the PhD grants come from the government (tax payers). 3 Who said the UK is "a developed" country. It is a country with pros and cons, like any other country.

Comment: In many countries, discriminating by *nation of origin* (ie. what country you came from before you became a citizen) is forbidden. Discriminating by *citizenship status* (ie. whether you became a citizen at all) is not, due to obvious legal and financial implications (student visa, you leaving to use your training for another country's benefit). Perhaps you are confusing the two?

Comment: "Why such discriminations are allowed in a developed country like the UK?" Because Britain puts its own people first, like most other countries. I expect you'd find similar results if you were applying to PHD programmes in other countries. Britain is not special in that respect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are many funded PhD programmes in the UK not open for non-EU applicants?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/why-are-many-funded-phd-programmes-in-the-uk-not-open-for-non-eu-applicants)

Comment: @vsz, I agree with the analogy, but we can also look at it as an investment from the UK government if they allow the movie watchers to pay their tickets once they finish the movie. This is what I see is the case with Norway, for instance. Many non-EU students end up living there, contributing to the economy, even becoming citizens. These students from poor countries, many of them do not think of returning to their countries.

Comment: If you were a UK citizen of non-caucasian heritage, you'd get in. It's not your ethnicity that is an issue, it is your citizenship. (It's not racism, it's... "citizen-ism"?)

Comment: @vsz, also if you take into account that the ratio of non-EU nationals residing in the UK---who pay the same taxes as the UK citizens but don't get the same benefits---is probably the same as that of non-EU students studying in the UK, then it is not true that these non-EU students haven't got their tickets. The UK government receive taxes not from their citizens only, but also from citizens of other countries who reside on their land.

Comment: @QuangThinhHa: UK students are expected to pay lots of taxes to the UK through their life as a result of their education. You might try to get money from your own government. If you succeed, do you think it would be discrimination if your own government didn't pay the same for British students studying in the UK>

Comment: **Please take extended discussion to [chat].**

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but possibly another side to it. Most PhD students I know at my own UK university are funded by STFC or EPSRC, both of which are tied to UK/EU. **However, don't give up hope!** There are at least 2 non-EU students in my group, and I (a UK citizen) am funded directly by the Department so don't have to be a UK/EU citizen. The point is, there are other sources out there, and larger groups will often have a couple of studentships available to people they really want to are not EU. So if you find a supervisor who really wants you, they will find the money!

Comment: @adipro: However, I was told by a colleague in Norway that they had a scholarship which explicitly required them to either return to their home country or pay back (not sure whether some or all of) the scholarship if they stay in Norway. I believe we have a similar system here in Germany. The reasoning I'm aware of is that such scholarships are paid for by money that is allocated explicitly to help poor countries by giving good education to students so they can help improving the situation in their home country.

Comment: @cbeleites, that is for Masters as I far as I am aware. Still, if they return to their countries, they do not need to pay anything. PhD students are paid a salary and they pay tax.

Comment: There are also other opportunities than a fully funded programme, for instance in Netherlands it is common for a PhD to be structured on similar basis as an employment contract. Many Universities offer fees reduction for their own employees (i.e. you could get a job as a Research Assistant and then do your PhD part-time).

Answer (score 71):

I wrote a pretty extensive response on this a little while ago: [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61795/fellowships-for-graduate-studies-in-uk-which-are-available-currently/61800#61800) and also [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62885/phd-funding-other-sources/62886#62886) may be slightly relevant.

The short version is: Because they can be, and because they have to be. UK universities make money off international students; their funding is limited, and it is designed to go to domestic or European students. The funding bodies will only fund domestics because a) they're probably not allowed to fund anyone else; b) it's in their best interests to fund domestics; c) one international PhD scholarship would be equal to 2 or 3 domestic ones.

There is also the over-arching idea in the UK governmental system that students are supposed to bring in money, not take it. This idea has spiked in magnitude in the past few years.

The UK government limits the funding given to universities, and universities make up for that with international fees. We are essentially cash cows, outside the rare scholarships that are extremely competitive (Rhodes, Fullbright - the second of which neither of us is eligible for).

You also can't go for the option of naturalisation based on the time you've been in the country because -- you guessed it -- time as a student doesn't count.

Source: Same situation as you, left friends, home, and partner to do PhD in France after 5 years in Britain. I had many PhD acceptances, but none of the universities could fund me and we spent months looking at every option. Unless you're rich and you can self-fund (or you're happy to take out loans), it's unfortunately not very doable right now.

You should also keep in mind that, as a student at the end of your education, you are unfortunately likely to be targeted by the immigration police. I would advise you to not do anything like overstay, but also to not leave the UK once you have graduated until you're ready to move away before the expiry of your tier 4 visa -- because you will not be allowed back in even if your visa has months of validity on it. It happened to me. This is unrelated to your question, but it's a warning I think not enough people in our situation get.

Comment: Very interesting answer.  Does this phenomenon apply to American PhD programs, i.e., do American applicants have an easier time gaining admission with funding than do international applicants?  I suspect that this is not the case, but this is just an observation of the Dept that I am currently in, which consists of probably 90% international Chinese PhD students.

Comment: I really want to upvote your answer for now, but the bloody 15 reputations is holding me back from doing so... :( I think chinese students have their government funding (CSC) which many other governments don't have. It is more like "if you accidentally come from a poor country, we are sorry for you but that'st it"...

Comment: @User001 do you mean PhD programmes in the US? Or do you mean Americans in the UK? If the former, I've no idea, hopefully somebody can answer. If the latter, no, Americans are treated exactly the same as everyone else, including PhD graduates being imprisoned and deported after applying for LTR.

Comment: @QuangThinhHa Are you on a tier 4 visa right now?

Comment: @lafemmecosmique yes...

Comment: @QuangThinhHa OK, then I'm sorry but between your graduation ceremony and your visa expiry (should be 3 mos later) you can't leave if you need to be able to get back. This isn't explicitly stated in the rules anywhere, but it is the case as told to me by the border patrol agents when I was detained. You won't be let in again. You are expected to pack up and leave at the first opportunity, essentially, and by leaving you are waiving the remaining days of your visa, as long as the date of your graduation ceremony has already passed.
So you could go to Rio, but you'd have to go elsewhere after.

Comment: I highly recommend PhD programmes in Europe for your situation.

Comment: Ultimately, many PhD programmes in the UK are funded by the UK government through the research councils.  The UK government has no particular interest in funding foreign students who will be expected to leave the country at the end of their studies.  They would rather be educating British citizens, but they aren't allowed to discriminate against EU citizens (who would be allowed to stay in the UK afterwards, anyway).

Comment: You really need to explain what you mean by *one international PhD scholarship would be equal to 2 or 3 domestic ones*. WRT cost (*why!?*), WRT expected outcome (*WHY?!*).

Comment: @Ghanima cost, because PhD funding covers tuition fees and the host University would look to levy the international fees for a non-EU student

Comment: @User001: At the Ph.D. level, there is, by and large, no distinction between international students and U.S. citizens when it comes to *scholarships* and such. However, if you plan to or have to augment your disposable income from *loans*, then only in rare cases (students at business and law schools in the old days) this will be possible. So I would definitely add the U.S. as a target country as long as your scholarship offered is large enough,

Comment: @User001 University tuition in the USA is a state, not federal, matter. Often residents of the state get a favorable rate compared to non-residents. Funding sources may be restricted. For example, "Those who do not hold United States citizenship, national, or permanent resident status by the application deadline." are not eligible for the NSF Graduate Research Fellowship Program.

Comment: @User001 I think you'll find most (all?) American universities will be happy to take you in, so long as they get paid one way or another. If you apply to a publicly funded school like UC or CSU you may even have an advantage, as they expect international and out-of-state students to pay more.
Keep in mind, US universities always expect $$$, usually on the order of $20k-40k per year. So you won't exactly have a free ride like in EU/UK :)

Comment: Hi @gnometorule, when you say "no distinction..." do you mean that an American PhD program would not considerably favor an American PhD applicant over, say, a European or Chinese Phd application -- and that the admission and funding offers are strictly based on merit?  As I commented to lafemmecosmique, I think this might be the case, just from my observations of the department that I am currently in.  Thanks,

Comment: However, if there *is* some favorable consideration for American applicants, @gnometorule, then I wonder whether I am underestimating myself regarding Phd applications.  For example, one of my American classmates who has moved on from our school is currently doing her PhD at Princeton.  When her advisor gave her a list of suggested schools to apply to, she was genuinely shocked.  I know that she is incredibly well-prepared and very bright, but I do wonder whether American PhD programs, say, in the STEM fields, would like to have more American applicants.  What are your thoughts?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @PatriciaShanahan, yes, I am aware of the NSF grants that are available only to Americans.  Interestingly, some of my PhD-level American friends, who work their butts off to apply and win those grants, found out later that their overall PhD funding does *not* increase - i.e., the students bringing in the NSF grants did not get an increase in stipend.  All the money goes to the school, and they were definitely pissed off about it -- it was a top "anonymous" complaint to faculty members in our Department.

Comment: Hi @nick, "...get paid one way or another"...meaning...the funding (if offered) is *earned* by lots of teaching, grading and office hours - and that its nothing even close to "free money"?  Thanks,

Comment: In the fields and schools I'm somewhat familiar with (stem or near stem, and at the better-ranked private universities, although it's probably similar at state schools), it's almost exclusively merit-based. Yes, all things equal, an American candidate might be chosen (in particular if minority). But my program was almost exactly 50/50, and the terms of scholarships, etc, identical. It was the same for my wife - actually, probably more international there -, and other friends. The schools are in the ballpark of Princeton - I was accepted there, say, with full scholarship, being European@User001

Comment: @User001: As others have commented on out-of-state tuition being higher at state schools if you're no California, say, resident, this may or may not make a difference. Twin Cities, say, offered me a full scholarship, but I also wasn't accepted by two (or was it just 1? I forgot) California state schools that were ranked (in the field I applied to) much below the private schools offering me admission. However, don't be dissuaded from applying there either: it can work, as I noticed first hand.

Comment: @User001 By that I meant American universities doesn't necessarily care so much where you're from and how you're able to fund your studies. There are scholarships available but I think international students will have a harder time acquiring funding. I have no experience with work programs so not sure if I can answer your question properly- all I can say is merit is the primary consideration, and how you cover the costs is up to you. It's not really a big factor in admissions- they publish the costs and they assume you will pay it if admitted

Comment: Ah, very interesting, @gnometorule.  Thanks so much for your help -- and congratulations to you and your wife :-)

Comment: all my advisors finished Phds in UK, @QuangThinhHa They are all asians, I am shocked that UK dont provide scholarships, that is not true. pelase contact me if you need contacts.

Comment: @Ghanima because international students, even PhD students, have to pay international tuition. they already need a living stipend like domestic students, *but their scholarship would also have to cover their tuition*. At my undergrad institution the domestic tuition price was £9k, and the international student price for PhD was £20k. *per year*. that is why

Answer (score 37):

In addition to the other answer, I think a big problem you are facing is that you and the UK government do not having matching expectations of what a PhD student position is. You say:

> Having chosen the UK to study with the belief that 'as long as I am competent I should be qualified for the job', the reality has really slapped back at me.

In terms of UK education policy, and as I understand it, a position as a PhD student is not a "job" like being a lawyer or gardener. It's a funded educational program, where the country partially or wholly pays for your training. As the UK is spending this money, they want this benefit to go primarily or exclusively to UK citizens (and EU citizens, arguably mostly because they have to). Whether this is a good policy or a bad one is really not a question that is easy to answer, but this is fundamentally the reason for the hardship you are facing.

That being said, you are not out of options. You can:

- Find a position in the UK that is funded via European money (e.g., H2020 or ERC) or industry funding, rather than UK funds. Those should pretty much always be freely assignable even to PhD students.
- Move to any other country in the European Union. No other major country that I am aware of (including Germany, Switzerland, France, and Sweden) has similar restrictions, and a master from a good UK university should open up this possibility for you.

Comment: Unfortunately a EU funded project in the UK will probably not work, as the PhD funding is a fixed amount and only covers domestic University fees and not international ones.

Comment: @Avelina I am not sure whether that is right. Universities / departments can set their own cost rate in H2020  projects, and I see no reason why a rational department would set a rate that limits them in what students they can put onto the position (also I know a few international students in UK universities that work on European projects).

Answer (score 33):

Here's an alternative way of looking at it:

Education is one of the UK's main exports.

The aim is to sell education to those from other countries, not to give them money and education. You might not agree with that, but it's the current situation.

Answer (score 14):

UK research councils cannot and indeed do not discriminate only by nationality. Eligibility mostly depends instead on residence. See for example [ESRC's summary](http://www.esrc.ac.uk/skills-and-careers/studentships/prospective-students/am-i-eligible-for-an-esrc-studentship/) .

In general, people who have been ordinarily resident in the UK for 3 years are eligible for research council studentships, regardless of their nationality/citizenship. Note, the caveat that for non-EU citizens, time spent in the UK for the purpose of full-time education does not count towards this.

As a result, not only are a large number of non-EU citizens eligible for studentships. But also, there are some Brits, who, having live abroad, are not eligible.

As others have said, the reason for restricting funding in this way is that the Government view PhD studentships as an investment in the UK and so limit their availability. Various pieces of UK and European law shape the restrictions into the (somewhat complicated) form you see.

Applying limits to tax-payer funded studentships in this way is not unique to the UK, here is a similar [example from Chile](http://www.conicyt.cl/becas-conicyt/2016/01/becas-doctorado-en-el-extranjero-bch-2016/) , that requires the applicant 'Ser chileno/a o extranjero/a con permanencia definitiva en Chile' -> 'To be Chilean or a foreigner with permanent residency in Chile'. While, in the USA, the [NSF Graduate Research fellowship program](https://www.nsfgrfp.org/applicants/eligibility) requires applicants to 'be a US citizen, US national, or permanent resident'.

Answer (score 7):

Some answers already point in this direction, but I think this will bring more clarity.

Residence in a country entails having a series of rights and obligations. For example the payment of VAT that non-residents can recover when they leave the country. Access to public health or social benefits .. and the same with education.

Citizens of European Union have mutually recognized rights, so that citizens of an European country have certain rights as if they were residents. In other cases you just have to comply some small formalities to obtain these rights (eg request European health card when they are in transit).

They don't need special permits to work or fix residence, etc.

Overseas citizens do not have the same rights, maybe they need to fix residence before applying for a job, a travel visa, vaccination or whatever. And same applies to UK or European citizens when travelling abroad.

---

Edit: someone mentioned Spain.

Prerequisites for obtaining fundings in universities in Spain are:

Being Spanish, or possessing the nationality of a Member state of the European Union. In the case of Union citizens or their families, beneficiaries of the rights of free movement and residence will be required to have the status of permanent residents or proving to be employed or self-employed. These requirements shall not apply for obtaining scholarship tuition. In the event of non-EU foreigners, the provisions shall apply the rules on rights and freedoms of foreigners in Spain and their social integration.

[Source](http://www.mecd.gob.es/educacion-mecd/mc/becas/2015/estudios-universitarios/requisitos.html%20%22Requisitos%20generales%20becas%20MEC%202015-2016%20Ministerio%20de%20Educaci%C3%B3n%20y%20Ciencia)

Answer (score 5):

Is there any country whose tax-funded universities do *not* differentiate between foreign and domestic residents (and others defined as equivalent to domestic for educational purposes, under specific international treaties such as EU membership, or student exchange agreements)?  The UK is hardly alone in this practice.

Comment: France. Source: I got the same funding as any French or EEA person would get, and I'm American. And this is for a government stipend.
I think Germany and most of Europe is like this.
And I know that Australia is not like this.

Comment: Do they treat internationals, applying from abroad, the same as domestic students for purposes of admission (if the program is selective)?  Admitting a limited number of foreigners and giving them the same level of funding as domestic residents is done at some schools in the US and UK, but this is not the same as treating everyone equally.

Comment: In my experience, yes, the same. I interviewed in the same place and on the same day as everyone else did, drawn from the same funding pot. Also in France AFAIK they actually have to interview *every single candidate*, so there isn't shortlisting/selection as such.

Comment: That's consistent with the internationals competing for a more limited number of places.  By selection I mean admission selection; is the probability of admission the same for identically qualified foreign and domestic applicants.  It *could* be that there is an absolutely level playing field where if the program accepts 50 applicants per year, and 80 percent of the most qualified applicants are from outside France (or EU, French former colonies, etc), then 40/50 accepted will be foreigners.  But that would be a very unusual arrangement, if it really exists anywhere on a large scale.

Comment: I *was told* that the nationality was not taken into account at all, but I don't have a specific source about that. Just that "The way the grants are awarded is transparent and is based essentially on the academic merit. After a pre-selection based on the evaluation of the electronic or paper document, an oral presentation is done by the candidate." http://bit.ly/1N9WfUc i'll keep looking, maybe i can find something else

Comment: Spain also... I have to say that I am agree with op that this practice is racist or discriminatory by definition. Citizenship is extremely hard to get in some countries it is plain discrimination treat residents without it like second class people. You must pay all the taxes but enjoy only a limited amount of benefits.

Comment: This does not answer the question.