# Should I self-fund my PhD at one of the top 10 universities at UK?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, funding, united-kingdom

I will start my PhD in the field of Biomedical Computer Vision soon at one of the top 10 universities at UK. I am an international student from Asia. 
But unfortunately I haven't received any source of funding yet (no university scholarship, no supervisor grant) to cover my PhD. The tuition fees alone per year is only slightly less than 20,000 British Pounds, which is something I cannot afford on my own for all my years of PhD.

I am thinking of going there initially for one year with self-funding, by taking money from my savings and some from my parents, and will risk it initially and try to secure a source of funding there after starting my PhD, and if everything goes well will have figured a way to fund myself from some grant or scholarship.

I have been thinking about this since many many days now and am not able to make a decision about whether I should go there or not. And if things go really bad financially, what would be ways out ?

Any comments or help is much needed and highly appreciated.

Comment: Doing a PhD is questionable financial proposition even when it's funded. Self funding is not a good investment. Also, I doubt your ability to find funding after you have started. I do not know who you would apply for funds from.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad investment. What is your life goal? A career in academia?

Comment: No. And you are unfortunately unlikely to find funding, because of these reasons. (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66687/why-is-discrimination-based-on-citizenship-allowed-in-phd-funding-in-the-uk/66689#66689)