# Getting a physics PhD from Cambridge with self funding?

Tags: phd

I will probably not be able to secure any funding. I can self fund the costs, but I heard that this is looked down upon and most advisors would not want to spend time with me as I am inferior to others who have gotten funding which will hurt the quality of my research and publications.

Is this true? Will self funding my PhD make it harder for me to find advisors and will I be looked down upon/ produce worse publications?

I know that similar questions exist, but I am mainly asking if advisors will be less willingly to become my advisors if I am self funded (do they think students who got funding have more potential than those that did not refuse funding)?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71794/should-i-self-fund-my-phd-at-one-of-the-top-10-universities-at-uk